# Why won't the pivot point/3D cursor move to center of object anymore?

Tags: 3d-cursor

When I started using Blender whenever I clicked an object the pivot point would immediately be at the center of whatever I clicked.

Now it just stays where it was last put and doesn't move until you manually do it.

How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have you piviot point set wrong, try <kbd>,</kbd> on your keyboard:

[image]

In red is what you have it set to, in green are options that will achieve the result you want

Comment: Red boxes especially. yay!