# Center Off Center - Why?

Tags: mesh

Sometimes the "center point" of a sphere, cube, etc. is off center from its object, even sometimes outside the object.  The manipulator stays with the center point.
Is there a way to keep this from happening?
I've seen how to cure it, but I'd like to know how/why it happens.
It's very offputting (if you'll pardon the pun).

Is there a way to cause it in a controlled manner?

Comment: [Related (and possible duplicate of)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26835/why-wont-the-pivot-point-3d-cursor-move-to-center-of-object-anymore)

Answer (score 3):

Because you are trying to move your object in *Edit mode*. If you want to move your WHOLE object (along with its origin point), move it in *Object mode*. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to quickly switch between *Object mode* and *Edit mode*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is new addon maybe helpful for everybody. 
Install this [addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrYGXg5HjMA)

Under tool -> Modify Pivot

In object mode in modify pivot addon click the Modify pivot and you will get and empty just click the empty and move where u need. And to confirm just press commit pivot in the tools -> modify pivot addon

Now you can rotate

[image]

Comment: I suspect that setting the pivot point type is the answer to this question.  See comment above.  However not sure setting the pivot point location, via an addon is.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will save you! It will let you place the origin at the centre of mass.